# Python loop skipping one element while looping

Tags: python, loops, selenium

I have this code that loops over `Top Alexa 1000` websites, and get the ones that allow `Sign Up` or `Login` in any form. If there is a website in one of the iterations of this loop that gets stuck or throws `Exception` in any form, I remove that from my list, and start the loop over again with the next element. I am using the `selenium` package in `Python` to do this. It works fine, except the fact that for some reason its looping over every other element in my `alexa_1000` list-containing variable (i.e. skipping one element), rather than going over each element. Could anyone please help? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code that I can see, and I have been debugging it to see the program flow, but really can't figure out whats happening. The general flow of the program seems to be fine. When I print the index of each loop, to see the nature of skipping, that also seems fine in the sense of going from 0 to 1 to 2 to 3. Would be glad of any help. Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def get_alexa_top_pages():

    sites = []

    with open('topsites_1000.txt', 'r') as f:

        for line in f:
            line = line.strip('\n')
            sites.append(line)

    sites = filter(None, sites)


    sites = ['http://www.' + site for site in sites]

    return sites

def main():

    alexa_1000 = get_alexa_top_pages()
    out = open('sites_with_login.txt', 'w')
    sign_in_strings = ['sign in', 'signin', 'login', 'log in', 'sign up', 'signup']

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

    for index, page in enumerate(alexa_1000):


        try:

            print "Loading page %s (num %d)" %(page, index + 1)
            driver.get(page)
            html_source = driver.page_source
            html_source = html_source.lower()
            present = any([i in html_source for i in sign_in_strings])
            if present:
                out.write(page + '\n')

            alexa_1000.remove(page)

        except TimeoutException as ex:
            alexa_1000.remove(page)
            continue
        except Exception as ex:
            alexa_1000.remove(page)
            continue    


    out.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Removing an element while enumerating a collection will interfere with the enumeration.

Comment: @Jerry101 I added enumerate only later to test it out, otherwise the usual `for page in alexa_1000` was having the same effect.

Comment: Yes, I meant "enumerating" in the sense of looping over the values. This common gotcha arises because the loop remembers to provide the `n`th item next, and deleting an earlier item shifts items downwards so the item that was at `collection[n]` moved to `collection[n-1]`. One fix is to loop over the collection backwards: `for page in alexa_1000[::-1]:` so shifting later items downwards won't interfere. Another fix is to make a temporary copy, as explained in [The for statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

Comment: @Jerry101 Thanks so much for that explanation! :) Learnt something awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to get rid of the issue. The issue is because you are touching a enumeration while enumerating it. That should always be avoided. You can do that by rewriting your code

### Using sets instead of array

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def get_alexa_top_pages():

    sites = []

    with open('topsites_1000.txt', 'r') as f:

        for line in f:
            line = line.strip('\n')
            sites.append(line)

    sites = filter(None, sites)


    sites = ['http://www.' + site for site in sites]

    return sites

def main():

    alexa_1000 = set(get_alexa_top_pages())

    alexa_invalid = set()

    out = open('sites_with_login.txt', 'w')
    sign_in_strings = ['sign in', 'signin', 'login', 'log in', 'sign up', 'signup']

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

    for index, page in enumerate(alexa_1000):


        try:

            print "Loading page %s (num %d)" %(page, index + 1)
            driver.get(page)
            html_source = driver.page_source
            html_source = html_source.lower()
            present = any([i in html_source for i in sign_in_strings])
            if present:
                out.write(page + '\n')

        except TimeoutException as ex:
            alexa_invalid.add(page)
            continue
        except Exception as ex:
            alexa_invalid.add(page)
            continue    

    alexa_valid = alexa_1000 - alexa_invalid

    out.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In this you use set, one for looping and one for maintaining the list of invalid ones. If exception occurs you update the invalid one. At the end you can subtract the two to find valid sites as well

### Use reverse array and pop

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def get_alexa_top_pages():

    sites = []

    with open('topsites_1000.txt', 'r') as f:

        for line in f:
            line = line.strip('\n')
            sites.append(line)

    sites = filter(None, sites)


    sites = ['http://www.' + site for site in sites]

    return sites

def main():

    alexa_1000 = get_alexa_top_pages()

    out = open('sites_with_login.txt', 'w')
    sign_in_strings = ['sign in', 'signin', 'login', 'log in', 'sign up', 'signup']

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

    for index, page in enumerate(alexa_1000[::-1]):


        try:

            print "Loading page %s (num %d)" %(page, index + 1)
            driver.get(page)
            html_source = driver.page_source
            html_source = html_source.lower()
            present = any([i in html_source for i in sign_in_strings])
            if present:
                out.write(page + '\n')

        except TimeoutException as ex:
            alexa_1000.pop()
            continue
        except Exception as ex:
            alexa_1000.pop()
            continue    

    out.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In this you loop in reverse order and the ones which error out, you just pop them out. At the end `alexa_1000` will have all the valid websites which you processed

There would be lot many ways to approach this, above show just 2 of them that you can ideally use

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! I appreciate it a lot. The reverse array pop example is pretty cool.